# How to filter spotlight tracks in soundcloud API

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I'm currently working on an iOS app using the Soundcloud API, and it's working great so far. Something that I haven't been able to figure out, however, is how to construct an URL in order to get only the tracks pinned as spotlight tracks from a certain user.

For example, let's say I'm using the following URL:
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/username/tracks.json?client_id=mySecretId

I've carefully gone through the API documentation at developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/, but it feels like there's a subresource I'm missing.

I'm aware that I can use the created_at filter to show the most recently added tracks, but if I'm understanding the platform correctly, a spotlight track does not necessarily have to be one of the most recently added?

I would be ever so grateful for feedback on this subject!

Cheers

/Anders

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight is not available via public API, sorry.